# Update permalinks

Tags: database, wordpress, url, permalinks

I have added custom "folder" named Srpski to my permalink structure as you can see in .htaccess file below. So in WP Dashboard > Settings > Permalinks my custom permalink structure looks like this: http://webdizajntest.com/poljoprivredni-fakultet/**Srpski**/%postname%/

This is working great when i add new post or page. It's displaying their permalinks with **Srpski** in url structure and that is what i need because of maintaining PageRank.

Problem is with old pages and posts. Their permalinks do not have this "directory" **Srpski** in url structure because they were saved without it.

I have a lot of pages and posts and i can't make them from the beginning, so my question is **How can I update all existing page and posts permalinks in DB to have this structure with Srpski in URL?**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /poljoprivredni-fakultet/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /poljoprivredni-fakultet/Srpski/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Duplicate on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/123850/update-permalinks

Answer (score 0):

You can try switching to basic permalink structure (the one with post id format) and then again choose custom permalink.

Or you can use following plugin to write desired URL for each page

[Custom Permalink Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/)